# Distinct values in set

Tags: mysql

the problem is I don't know how to write a query that does what I want. I hope you can help. I have a table like this:

```
path (VARCHAR)            | info (VARCHAR) | method (SET)
------------------------------------------------------------
/                         | something      | GET
/cp/product/%             | something else | GET,PUT
/cp/product/edit/%        | yap yap        | DELETE,POST
```

What I want is a query which would show all methods available for the path, e.g. if I were to run something like this:

```
SELECT distinct_values_in_set(`method`) FROM `table` WHERE '/cp/product/edit/1337' LIKE `vpath`;
```

I'd expect a result set similar to

```
distinct_values_in_set(`method`)
--------------------------------
DELETE,GET,POST,PUT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct `method`)
FROM `table`
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: It will only concat distinct `method` fields, but don't prevent `GET` and `GET,PUT` to give you `GET,GET,PUT`.